# Material-UI show menu on IconButton click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking at the material-ui website and trying to achevie the following functionality - show a menu when an IconButton is clicked ?

As per the example it seems there is a lot of code involved? What is the purpose of anchorEl in the example shown https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/

Answer (score 1):

From the [MaterialUI Menu API page](https://material-ui.com/api/menu):

anchorEl: The DOM element used to set the position of the menu.